# How to show that the limit of $x(1+\sin(x)$ is not $\infty$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$?

Tags: limits, functions, proof-verification, proof-writing

Let $f(x)=x(1+\sin (x))$.

The definition of $f$ tends to infinity as $x$ tends to infinity is:

> For any $M>0$, there exists an $X$ such that, for all $x\ge X$, $f(x)\ge M$

So, the negation of the above statement means that $f$ does not tend to infinity as $x$ tends to infinity. I am not sure of the correct negation, but here is what I came up with:

> There exist an $M>0$,  such that for all $X$, $x\ge X$ implies $f(x)<M$

Is the above negation correct?

Besides that, I also came up with this proof to show that the limit of $x$ does not tend to infinity as $x$ tends to infinity:

Let $M=1$.

Therefore, $x=1$ implies $f(1)>M$.

Furthermore, $x=1 < \frac{3}{2}\pi$ and $f(\frac{3}{2}pi)=0$

Therefore, I have shown that there exists an $M>0$ such that if $f(x_0)>M$, there exists an $x$ such that $x>x_0$ and $f(x)<M$.

This does not sound like the negation of the definition of $f$ tends to infinity as $x$ tends to infinity but is this an acceptable proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not negate the "for all $x$" correctly.  The negation of your statement should be:

> There exists $M>0$ such that for all $X$, there exists $x\ge X$ such that $f(x)<M$.

Also, it would be even better to specify where $X$ comes from:

> There exists $M>0$ such that for all $X\in\Bbb R$, there exists $x\ge X$ such that $f(x)<M$.

In your proof, you have not addressed the issue of "for all $X$".  You need something like the following (I have included as much of your proof as possible).

Choose $M=1$.

Let $X\in\Bbb R$.

Choose $k$ to be a positive integer greater than $X$ and set $x=2k\pi+\frac32\pi$.  Then
$$x>2k\pi>k>X$$
and
$$f(x)=x(1+\sin({\textstyle\frac32}\pi))=x(1+(-1))=0<M\ .$$

Answer (score 2):

**A start:** Either consider $x=2n\pi$, or $x=2n\pi -\frac{\pi}{2}$.

**Remark:** In the post, the negation was not correctly dealt with. The negation of $(\forall x\ge X)(f(x)\ge M)$ is $(\exists x\ge X)(f(x)\lt M)$. I would suggest using informal reasoning, and not manipulation of logical expressions.